# Rails Clockwork events getting called twice locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, clockwork

When I run my clockwork file, events are registered twice. Am I doing something wrong?

CLI I'm running locally to test:
`clockwork app/lib/clockwork/clock.rb`

clock.rb:

```
require 'clockwork'
require 'active_support/time'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork
  handler do |job, time|
    puts "Running #{job} at #{time}"
    puts
  end

  every(1.hour, 'test') do 
    puts 'RUNNING TEST'
  end
end
```

The output:

```
I, INFO -- : Starting clock for 2 events: [ test test ]
I, INFO -- : Triggering 'test'
BLOCK RUNNING TEST
I, INFO -- : Triggering 'test'
BLOCK RUNNING TEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good amount of debugging I found it was because in my development.rb file I had:

`config.eager_load = true`

Which, combined with the

```
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'
```

Ran the clock file twice. I believe this is because I'm preloading the app (eager_load), and then loading again with the require statements?

Anyways, the eager_load is ignored when clockwork is ran from my procfile (tested with $ heroku local), so it works fine.

Hope this helps anyone as I was stuck on this for a while!

Comment: Where can I find the 'development.rb' file, please? I've a same problem of registering each event twice, but only in production on shared hosting...

Comment: This problem occured for me with dokku. The solution is correct, I've added to production.rb `config.eager_load = ENV["CLOCKWORK"].blank?` and in Procfile I'm calling `bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb CLOCKWORK=true`